# VBA replace code not working on text document from Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code to replace tabs with commas in a text document:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Path:\CSV.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
strTab = vbTab

strText = Replace(strText, strTab, ",")

objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Path:\CSV.txt", ForWriting)

objFile.Write strText

objFile.Close
```

This works fine on a unicode text document that I create myself, however throws up an error when used on a unicode text document created from excel.

Line: 16 
Char: 1 
Error: Invalid procedure call or argument 
Code:800A0005

Here is an example of a text file created from excel that gives the error:

[CSV.txt](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B4gu_M4o3bZ4VnNaSElib0hlMXc)

Can anyone see what is different about this text document that would be causing the error?

EDIT: I have just tried writing the result to a new text document instead of overwriting the same one, but this has just given a garbled result in the document:

```
ÿþa 黐멸ȯ                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 , , , , , 

 , , , , , , , 

 , , , , , , ,
```

EDIT2: the suggestion of using TristateTrue from 'Siddharth Rout' gets me past the initial 'Invalid procedure call' error, but now i'm stuck with the garbled Chinese character output - Can anyone advise as to how to fix this?

Comment: Could you tell us which is Line 16?

Comment: Line 16 is `objFile.Write strText`

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Path:\CSV.txt", ForWriting)
```

with

```
Kill "Path:\CSV.txt"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("Path:\CSV.txt", True, True)
```

Now try it

Comment: Did you replace `"Path:\CSV.txt"` with the relevant path?

Comment: Yes I have replaced the path and I have put it on two lines as in your post.

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't for me? I have just tried writing the result to a new text file instead of overwriting the same one, but this has just given a garbled result. (see edit to original post)

Comment: Try with `Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Path:\CSV.txt", ForReading)` with `TristateTrue` as shown [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: This gets me past the initial 'Invalid procedure call' error, but now i'm stuck with the garbled Chinese character output...